# How to do this the fastest way? Image arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, image-processing, optimization

I have a loop that is too slow in C#.  I want to know if there is a faster way to process through these arrays.  I'm currently working in .NET 2.0.  i'm not opposed to upgrading this project. This is part of a theoretical image processing concept involving gray levels.

- Pixel count (PixCnt = 21144402)
- g_len = 4625
- list1d - 1Dimensional array of an image with upper bound of the above pixel count.
- pg - gray level intensity holder.

This function creates an index of those values. hence pgidx.

```
int[] pgidx = new int[PixCnt];
sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (i = 0; i < PixCnt; i++)
{
    j = 0;
    pgidx[i] = 0;
    while (list_1d[i] != pg[j] && j < g_len) j++;
    if (list_id[i] == pg[j])
        pgidx[i] = j
}
sw.stop();
Debug.WriteLine("PixCnt Loop took" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

Comment: How long is too slow?

Comment: Your variable naming is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a dictionary to store what's in the `pg` array will speed it up. `g_len` is 4625 elements, so you will likely average around 2312 iterations of the inner while loop. Replacing that with a single hashed look up in a dictionary should be faster. Since the outer loop executes 21 million times, speeding up the body of that loop should reap big rewards. I'm guessing the code below will speed up your time by 100 to 1000 time faster.

```
var pgDict = new Dictionary<int,int>(g_len);
for (int i = 0; i < g_len; i++) pgDict.Add(pg[i], i);
int[] pgidx = new int[PixCnt];
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < PixCnt; i++) {
    if (pgDict.TryGetValue(list_id[i], out value)) pgidx[i] = value;
 }
```

Note that setting `pgidx[i]` to zero when a match isn't found is not necessary, because all elements of the array are already initialized to zero when the array is created.

If there is the possibility for a value in `pg` to appear more than once, you would want to check first to see if that key has already been added, and skip adding it to the dictionary if it has. That would mimic your current behavior of finding the first match. To do that replace the line where the dictionary is built with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < g_len; i++) if (!pgDict.ContainsKey(pg[i])) pgDict.Add(pg[i], i);
```

Comment: Your concept seems brilliant, but: I'm getting 'pgDict.Add(pg[i], i)' -- An item with the same key has already been added. The gray level values are not non-duplicate.

Comment: @RobertKoernke - I thought that might be a possibility, and mentioned that in my last paragraph. Now that you've said that is in fact the case, I've edited my answer to show the code that would deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

If the range of the pixel values in `pq` allows it (say 16 bpp = 65536 entries), you can create an auxiliary array that maps all possible gray levels to the index value in `pg`. Filling this array is done with a single pass over `pg` (after initializing to all zeroes).

Then convert `list_1d` to `pgidx` with straight table lookups.

If the table is too big (bigger than the image), then do as @hatchet answered.